# How to programmatically change combobox selected item in datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, combobox

How to programmatically change combobox selected item in datagridview?

Comment: Just change the cell value to **one of items** of the comboboxcolumn, it will auto select for you.

Comment: so give me code example in answer :) we all know theoretical part :)

Comment: Ether write answer or don't write nothing. 0 logic in writing my code here.

Answer (score 0):

Using brute force. Assuming you want to change the value of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in the column `colIndex` and row `rowIndex`, and the value index of the combobox is in the 0 position:

```
For jj = 0 To CType(myDatagrid.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Count - 1
    If CInt(CType(myDatagrid.Rows(colIndex).Cells(rowIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items(jj).row(0)) = myValue Then
        myDatagrid.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex).Value = CType(myDatagrid.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items(jj).row(0)
    End If
Next
```

Yes, I know this question was asked 6 years ago, but I haven't found the answer anywhere and I found it by myself. Hope it will be useful to someone.

The reason why `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` has not `selectedIndex` or `selectedValue` properties is beyond my grasp.

Answer (score -1):

In the DataGridView CellClick event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     string item = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
     comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;
}
```